# Merge and UNION records from two tables using JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, sql

How can i merge and `UNION` records from two tables using `JOIN`. For example let say i have the following Table A and B, and want to end up like Table C.

I want to extract and merge all `tableB.Item ID` which matches `tableA.Customer ID` and if there is more than one match then i want to create a new fields which holds the other.

//Table A

```
  Customer ID     Customer_Bill_Name.......                  
    XXX001           XXX Company Name......           
    XXX002           YYY Company Name......
```

//Table B

```
 Customer ID          Item ID 1           
     XXX001            WH15 02
     XXX001            600278        
     XX0002            600000
```

//Table C: I want to end up like this

```
  Customer ID     Customer_Bill_Name       Item ID 1            Item ID 2           
    XXX001         XXX Company Name         WH15 02             600278 
    XX0002         YYY Company Name         600000
```

Here is the SQL code i used to merge records using `JOIN`

```
       $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Customers.CustomerId,   
              Customers.Customer_Bill_Name, 
              Customers.WhichShipVia, 
              JrnlHdr.INV_POSOOrderNumber, 
              JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, 
              JrnlHdr.GoodThruDate, 
              JrnlHdr.CustomerSONo, 
              JrnlHdr.Reference, 
              JrnlHdr.TransactionDate, 
              JrnlRow.DistNumber, 
              JrnlRow.Quantity, 
              LineItem.ItemID, 
              LineItem.SalesDescription, 
              LineItem.PartNumber,
              LineItem.ItemDescription 
    FROM   Customers
    INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
    ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
    ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
    INNER JOIN JrnlRow // store sales order information
    ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BOMItems  // stores Bill of Materials attached to the sales order
    ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = BOMItems.AssemblyRecordNo
    INNER JOIN LineItem //Stores all Inventory Items
    ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber

   WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 
          AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder 
          AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
          AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber 
          AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0 
          AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = '2014-11-17' 
  ORDER  BY JrnlHdr.Reference,JrnlRow.DistNumber");
```

Comment: that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. the work arounds get ugly **VERY** fast, and since you've basically got an unbounded number of possible columns, I **STRONGLY** suggest you do a normal join then do the row->column conversion in client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), this join all values to one column.

```
select a.*, group_concat(b.ItemId) joined
from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.customerId = b.customerId
group by a.customerId, a.customer, a.company
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMERID  CUSTOMER    COMPANY         JOINED
XXX001      XXX         Company Name    600278,WH15 02
XXX002      YYY         Company Name    600000
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee640/5)

Comment: How can convert  group_concat to an array or explode individual?